# jQuery Clone missing masking

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

I have built this sample project where I am adding masking to a input control. That is working fine but when I add a clone row I am losing the masking. Is there a way to keep the masking on the clone rows?

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6IKv50


$('#clone').click(function() {
var row = $("[id='ddRow_0']").clone();
$("[id='ddRow_0']").after(row);
});
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Links (not a link, actually) to other sites aren't adequate.

Comment: That said, see some of the great many questions about jQuery and dynamically-generated elements here and elsewhere. You need to either bind event handlers after creation or use event delegation from a persistent containing element.

Comment: Jefferson I belive this is what you want https://dotnetfiddle.net/jDDrPl

Comment: Do you mean I can't use the doc.ready for the binding?